# How to hide/remove "url.com is now on full screen" message above Firefox when hovering

Tags: css, firefox

How do I remove "url.com is now on full screen" message when I hover the top-middle portion of the browser?

[image]

I tried adding

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */
#fullscr-toggler {display:none !important;}
#full-screen-warning-container{display:none!important}
```

into my userChrome.css

I also tried setting on `about:config`:

```
full-screen-api.warning.delay = 0
full-screen-api.warning.timeout = 0
```

but it still pops up.

Comment: hmm its not for general use its, mainly for local kioks. so as much as possible I dont want the user to exit from the page I set on the kiosk.

Comment: by the way you can actually edit it using userChrome.css under chrome folder on the firefox user profile .. I did even manage to hide all the navigation bar using it. I just dont know where to find all the properties to be set so I can hide the message.

Comment: I dont understand the down vote though.. as I provided the things I did before posting something here and its a valid question.. xD

Comment: @Pete: ... which he has said doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Pete that's for pre-Quantum it seems.

Comment: @Pete: userChrome.css is Firefox's user-defined chrome stylesheet. "Chrome" is a common term for a browser's UI (and is where Google Chrome gets its name from).

Comment: hmm thats why im trying to ask for help.. its not working on my end as it should. otherwise I wouldnt be posting here.. anyways I solved it by setting 

full-screen-api.warning.timeout = -1 and full-screen-warning.delay =-1

Comment: anyways Thanks for trying to help guys.. much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if for some reason this line on about:config doesnt work

```
full-screen-api.warning.delay = 0
full-screen-api.warning.timeout = 0
```

just set

```
full-screen-api.warning.delay = -1
full-screen-api.warning.timeout = -1
```

instead and it should be working fine.